# amazon glacier sdk for .net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I have downloaded amazon library for .net and i am using the glacier services to get the list of vaults but i am getting the following error. A suggestion would be appreciated.

> [AmazonGlacierException: Signature expired: 20121212T160552Z is now
>   earlier than 20121212T160907Z (20121212T161407Z - 5 min.)]
>          Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.endOperation(IAsyncResult result) +151
>          Amazon.Glacier.AmazonGlacierClient.ListVaults(ListVaultsRequest listVaultsRequest).

Answer (score 3):

This error is commonly caused by your local system clock being off by more than 5 minutes.  If this is a persistent problem you might consider configuring an NTP server on your machine to keep time in sync.